# Volley error, centralize error management

Tags: android, android-volley

I have to open the login activity if the server returns error 401,
instead of catch error type on any call like this, is it possible to centralize the error management in an unique point?

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                context.getString(R.string.error_network_timeout),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
        //TODO
    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
       //TODO
    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
      //TODO
    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
       //TODO
    }
}
```

i tried implementing my custom retrypolicy

```
@Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

        //HTTP 401 and 403
        if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            AuthFailureError er = (AuthFailureError) error;

            //HTTP 401
            if (er.networkResponse.statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {


                  Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                  context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                  request.deliverError(er);
            }
       }
  }
```

but the 401 error is still delivered to the onErrorResponse event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extending the `com.android.volley.Request` to create a custom Class to do so: this is called the Volley custom request. Then override the required method, and also override the `parseNetworkResponse()` to do something like this

```
@Override
    protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        if (response.statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            /* go to login */
        }  
    }
```

This should do it.